# popup link with the same target opens in different windows when clicked from different tab pages

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, popup, window.open

I have a html page called home.html.

On that page I have a link to open a popup, the html code is as follows:

```
<a href='javascript: void(0);' onclick='window.open("popup.html", "myTarget", "width=1000,height=750");'>open popup</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tLmgkjzy/

When I open home.html and click the link, the popup opens as expected.
When I open home.html from a 2nd tab of Google Chrome and click the link, the popup opens in another window.

So despite the same 'target' name (myTarget), the popup opens in seperate windows.

How can I open the popup from the 2nd Google Chrome tab in the same popup window as the popup opened from the 1st Google Chrome tab?

thx
Frederik

Answer (score 0):

Each browser tab has its own browsing context and that is why different tabs open different windows in this case. If you want to maintain context over multiple tabs, I suggest you use `localStorage` to maintain some state that you'd check each time you click on the link.